# Python get highest value that is equal to or less than x

Tags: python

So I have this one list `hex_rows`. This list has thousands of entries of type `HexRow`.

```
class HexRow:
def __init__(self, byte_count, address, record_type, data, checksum):
    self.byte_count = byte_count
    self.min_addr = address
    self.record_type = record_type
    self.data = data
    self.checksum = checksum
```

I also have a dictionary `ex_obj.charics`. This one has a lot of fields, but the only relevant one is `n_Address`.

```
ex_obj_hex_list = []
for ex_val in ex_obj.charics.values():
    templist = [t for t in hex_rows if t.min_addr <= ex_val.n_Address]
    tuple = (ex_val, templist[-1])
    ex_obj_hex_list.append(tuple)
```

As you can see, I'm trying to find the hex_row item where the `min_addr` field is equal to `n_Address`. If there is no equal value I want to get the highest `min_addr` value that is less than `n_Address`. Although the above code is working, it is very slow. I read about bisect somewhere but I'm not able to figure out how it works

Comment: If you use a list comprehension instead of a for loop, it will certainly speed up your computation, but maybe not as much as you are looking for: `ex_obj_hex_list = [(ex_val, [t for t in hex_rows if t.min_addr <= ex_val.n_Address][-1]) for ex_val in ex_obj.charics.values()]`.

Comment: @Linda You're right, this does make it a bit faster, but it still takes around a minute to finish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out how to get Bisect to work:

```
ex_val_hex_addr.append = []
for ex_val in ex_obj.charics.values():
    i = bisect_left(hex_rows, ex_val.n_Address)
    ex_val_hex_addr.append((ex_val, hex_rows[i - 1]))
```

I also needed to adjust my constructor for the `HexRow` object

```
class HexRow:
    def __init__(self, byte_count, address=None, record_type=None, data=None, checksum=None):
        if address is None:
            self.num_low_addr = byte_count
        else:
            self.byte_count = byte_count
            self.min_addr = address
            self.record_type = record_type
            self.data = data
            self.checksum = checksum

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.num_low_addr <= other

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Foo({})'.format(self.num_low_addr)
```